# Composition of Multivariate Gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

This question is teasing my intuition for a moment :

$X \sim N(0, S_1)$
$Y|X \sim N(X, S_2)$

Does $Y \sim N(0, S_3)$ with some $S_3 = f(S_1, S_2)$ like (for instance) $S_1 + S_2$ ?

What I found is that *if* $Y$ follows a normal distribution, so this distribution is $N(0,S_1+S_2)$, since :

- $E[Y] = E_X[E_Y[Y|X]] = E_X[X] = 0$
- $E[YY^T] = E_X[E_Y[YY^T|X]] = S_1+S_2$ because $S_2 = E_Y[(Y-X)(Y-X)^T|X] = E_Y[YY^T|X] - XX^T$ and $E_X[XX^T]=S_1$.

But my calculations to show that it *is* a normal distribution seem to lead nowhere, since my drawings are giving to my intuition some reasons to think it is true.

What I have done until now is using the formula : $$p(y)=\int p(y|x)p(x)dx$$ but multivariate gaussians seems to be too complicated to achieve this calculation.

Comment: If this is a problem for a course or from a textbook, etc, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far & where you're stuck.

Comment: This question is more about curiosity than anything else. I did post a question about an exercise I found in a book [there](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130984/minimizing-kl-divergence-from-a-given-distribution-according-to-a-graph) but this one is just something I am asking myself about. I am not even sure there is an answer. Is this self-study ? Because if it is, an not just curiosity, why most of the questions aren't tagged `[self-study]` ?  
But I can add some details about what I found if you want.

Comment: Curiosity as a motivation does not make a question self-study. However, a question that is essentially the same as a question that comes from a book or course can be self-study, even if the question itself didn't. The topic itself is somewhat fuzzy. If this isn't from a book or a course, you don't have to tag it `[self-study]`.

Comment: However, the question isn't quite clear to me. 1st, in the last line, should "Y" be something else (Z, perhaps)? After all, you already know what Y is by stipulation. 2nd the last line doesn't quite form a grammatical question. Are you asking if Y (Z) *could be distributed as* N(0, S3)?

Comment: No, I want to know the marginal distribution of Y given its conditionnal distribution subject to X. Things about sum or product of gaussian distributions are well known, but as said in the title, I am here interested on their composition.